# setReadOnly not working on PostgreSQL Connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, readonly

I have a problem setting a read-only connection with a PostgreSQL database using JDBC.

I'm creating an application which loads queries to execute from a file, and I want to execute only SELECT (read-only) queries. Setting permissions on users who will run the application is not an option, so setting permissions at code level through the `Connection.setReadOnly(boolean)` method was the only option I could think of.

Now the problem is that I tried my application for an insert and delete query and they run normally, so my solution does not work.

Any tips on how to solve the problem?

Here below the simple code snippet which I'm testing:

```
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    connectAndExecute();
}

public static void connectAndExecute() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Connection connection;

    String connString = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, "user", "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    try {
        connection.setReadOnly(true);
        connection.createStatement().execute("delete from testtable");
        // connection.createStatement().execute("insert intotesttable(testfield1)values('test')");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the JDBC driver I'm using

```
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>42.2.10</version>
```

PostgreSQL version: 11.6

Comment: And if you execute `SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY` (which is what `setReadOnly(true)` does) in the database and try to execute those deletes and inserts, what happens?

Comment: `setReadOnly()` seems to only work if you disable auto commit

Comment: Thank you! It works in both the suggested cases. I tried the "set session characteristics" query and disabling autocommit and in both the cases insert and delete queries correctly raise an exception. Do you have any tip on which solution to prefer?

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to the pgjdbc driver team. In any case, you should prefer using the JDBC API over using database specific commands, if only for the sake of portability.

Comment: Thank you all, ill add the accepted answer putting both the workarounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems related to a bug of the driver.

These two workaround both worked for me:

- proposed by kayaman:

executing first the sql command

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION READ ONLY
```

- proposed by a_horse_with_no_name:

disabling auto-commit makes the setReadOnly call effective

```
Connection.setAutoCommit(false);
Connection.setReadOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear : the specification for setReadOnly method does not aim to prevent from updating the database.

As the Java's API says :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setReadOnly-boolean-

"Puts this connection in read-only mode as a hint to the driver to enable database optimizations"

So it is not a good idea to rely on this method in order to secure anything related to the need of having readonly transactions :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Todde's comment - you don't need to setAutoCommit(false), if you set readOnlyMode to always:

```
   /**
   * Connection parameter to control behavior when
   * {@link Connection#setReadOnly(boolean)} is set to {@code true}.
   */
  READ_ONLY_MODE(
      "readOnlyMode",
      "transaction",
      "Controls the behavior when a connection is set to be read only, one of 'ignore', 'transaction', or 'always' "
          + "When 'ignore', setting readOnly has no effect. "
          + "When 'transaction' setting readOnly to 'true' will cause transactions to BEGIN READ ONLY if autocommit is 'false'. "
          + "When 'always' setting readOnly to 'true' will set the session to READ ONLY if autoCommit is 'true' "
          + "and the transaction to BEGIN READ ONLY if autocommit is 'false'.",
      false,
      new String[]{"ignore", "transaction", "always"}),
```

See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/PGProperty.java